# Store object from API to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use ReactJS to store info provided by a backend API.
My backend API returns a JSON object which contains:

```
"a": 123
"b": 345
"c": 0
```

The above object is stored under *data* from my backend API.

So now I would like to store these values in *data* separately in React State as follows:

```
this.state = {
first:'',
second: '',
third: '',
}

//ComponentDidMount happen here
.then(result => {
        first: //result.data.data value "a":123 will be stored to State *First*
        //and "b":345 will go to second and "c":0 to third
        }
        debugger;
      })
```

What should I write for that part for storing information to state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
//ComponentDidMount happen here
.then(result => {
    first.setState(result.data.data.a);
    second.setState(result.data.data.b);
    third.setState(result.data.data.c);
}
debugger;
})
```

Comment: isn't that `object` from your code should be change to `data`

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with using `0, 1, 2` instead `'first', 'second', 'third'`, you can map through the values of the object and for each index store it in state

---

```
  .then(result => Object.values(result).map((value, i) => this.setState({ [i]: value })))
```

---

Do notice that the actual keys in the state gonna be in a type of string, so you can access them like `this.state['0']`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, may I know the process of using `first, second, third`? 
another question, how do I check the value of `i`? is it `console.log.i`? or just `console.log.1`?

Comment: `i` stand for "index" and for each `value` it gonna increase by one.

if for some reason you have to use alphabetic keys such `first`, you should create another function that translates index numbers into English words

Comment: hmm let me see, so is it `a: "123"` will be stored into `0`?
Wait, is this an array or `0, 1, 2` is actually a variable in `State`?

Comment: because I mapped over `values` I don't look at all on `keys` (e.g `a, b, c`).

 `0, 1, 2` are just equal to `first, second, third` as state keys, but they corresponded to a normal map index behavior so its kinda nice

Comment: @HagaiHarari I think the OP didn't understand how to access the `keys` in state (so am I ) let say if I want to store `0, 1, 2` to *localStorage*, should I perform like this: `localStorage.setItem('FirstValue', 0)` ?

Comment: localStorage.setItem('FirstValue', this.state['0'])